# How to remove highlighted but unselected listview item?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, listviewitem

I have this listview where I can delete a listview item from a dialog positive button. Scenario is: I have a 5-item listview initially and no item is highlighted yet.

```
1.Superman
2.Batman
3.Ironman
4.Aquaman
5.Spiderman
```

I select Batman item and delete it successfully through

```
myRecordingList.remove(myRecording);
objRowAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

through the dialog positive button. Now the problem is that the listview highlight goes now to Ironman item and it cannot be deleted if I delete it without really clicking Ironman item.

Is it possible to delete an item from a listview without selecting an item? How can I implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you select an item then remove this item from the ArrayAdapter and then just set the list adapter with the Array adapter.

```
lv.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

in dataAdapter remove your selected item.

Comment: Sorr, I don't quite get it. How can I set it? Can you show me the code?